# Probability - 12 pairs of shoes

Tags: probability, combinatorics

There are 12 pairs of shoes in a closet. Five shoes are picked at random.

(a)What is the probability there is no "pseudo-pair"(i.e., one left and one right shoe)?

(b) What is the probability that there is no pair?

I calculated the sample size to be |S| = (24 choose 2) 
For (a) the event A where there is no pseudo pair |A| = (12 choose 2) so that P(A) = |A|/|S| would this be correct or am I missing something ?

And for part (b) wouldn't the answer be the same as in part (a) ? Or perhaps I'm misinterpreting the question ?

Comment: There are  $\binom{24}{5}$ equally likely possible choices.

Comment: Presumably the pairs are all different? One left loafer and one right brogue would count as a pseudo pair. So there are many more pseudo pairs that real pairs.

Comment: I interpreted a "psuedo pair" to be any left and any right shoe.  To not get a psuedopair your chosen shoes have to be all left or all right.

Comment: I have given an answer interpreting the first part to mean that true pairs may be there, but "pseudo-pairs" are disallowed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are  $\binom{24}{5}$ equally likely possible choices of $5$ shoes.  We want the probability that all the shoes are left shoes or all right shoes, There are $\binom{12}{5}$ ways to choose all left, and the same number of ways to choose all right. So the required probability is $\frac{2\binom{12}{5}}{\binom{24}{5}}$.

As to the probability of no matching pair of shoes, we count the number of ways to choose $5$ shoes, no two of which form a pair. There are $\binom{12}{5}$ ways of choosing $5$ shoe "types." For each such choice, there are $2^5$ ways to choose the actual shoes, for a total of $\binom{12}{5}2^5$. For the probability, divide by $\binom{24}{5}$.

**Another way:** We solve the second problem. A similar but easier argument deals with the first problem. Imagine picking the shoes one at a time.

Whatever shoe we picked first, the probability the second does not match is $\frac{22}{23}$. Given that there was no match in the second pick, there are $22$ shoes left, of which $20$ don't match either of the first two. So the probability of no match after the third pick is $\frac{22}{23}\cdot \frac{20}{22}$. Given there was no match among the first $3$, the probability of no match on the fourth is $\frac{18}{21}$. Continue, it's almost over.

Answer (score 0):

I interpret the first part to mean that true pairs may be there, but "pseudo-pairs" are disallowed.

Thus $3$ cases arise: (i) $5 L$ or $5 R\;\;$ (ii) $1$ true pair + $3L$ or $3 R\;\;$ (iii) $2$ true pairs and $1 L$ or $1 R$ more

and $Pr = \dfrac{2\dbinom {12}5 +\dbinom{12}1\cdot2 \dbinom{11}3 +\dbinom{12}2\cdot2 \dbinom{10}1}{\dbinom{24}{5}}$

And just for completeness, for part two, with the numerator ruling out pair formations,

$Pr = \dfrac{24\cdot22\cdot20\cdot18\cdot16}{24\cdot23\cdot22\cdot21\cdot20}$